# I used the django EmailMessage to send an email, but in some mailbox, the attachment's filename show as messy code

Tags: python, django, encode

How to fix this issue, maybe can set the encode of attachment filename? The attachment name is Chinese

```
mail = EmailMessage(connection=connection)
mail.from_email = settings.HERA_EMAIL_USER
mail.subject = sub
mail.to = [to_user_email]
mail.body = body
mail.attach(u'{}.xlsx'.format(sub), dt.xlsx)
```

Comment: Please provide some relevant code snippets of the approach you've tried.

Comment: `mail = EmailMessage(connection=connection)`
`mail.from_email = settings.HERA_EMAIL_USER`                           `mail.subject = sub`
`mail.to = [to_user_email]`
`mail.body = body`
`mail.attach(u'{}.xlsx'.format(sub), dt.xlsx)`

Comment: The attachment's file name will show as messy code